# How to use GetElementsByClassName() on dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i got a little problem i want to query my database so when the user use the autocomplete i can get the stock of that product on another column 'td' called ***Exist Act *** , Ok now with this new scrip when i moveout of the any textbox it change the value of All of the **Exist Act** column.Is there a solution so the script just change the value on the same row? 
**this is my code i have changed the whole script, this one**

```
$(document).on("mouseout",".service",function(){//begin event
    var $this=$(this);
    var service = $(this).val();        
    var dataString = 'service='+service;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "busca.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {  

     $('.txtHint').html(data);
     }
      });
       });
```

**insted of this one**

function showUser(str) {

```
if (str == "") {
  document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
  return;
} else {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "busca.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form action="levantar_pedido2.php" method="post" name="form1" target="cuerpo">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="left">
    <tr class="Estilo9">
      <td width="20" align="center ">-</td>
      <td width="1" align="left"><strong>Cantidad</strong>
      </td>
      <td width="50" align="left"><strong>Exist Act *</strong>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="left"><strong>Descripcion</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" value="X" name="articulo[]" id="articulo" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" value="">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="txtHint">*</div>
      </td>
      <td align="left">
        <input onmouseout="showUser(this.value)" type="text" size="50" id="service" class="service" name="service[]" />
        <div align="right" class="suggestions"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center">

    <div class="inputs"></div>

  </table>

  <br>
  <A class="btn btn-default" id="adder" href="#">Áñadir otro que no este en la lista</A>


  <div align="right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Levantar pedido"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Levantar pedido</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**And this is my js for the dynamic inputs**

```
function addInput() {
    $('.inputs').append(
        '<table " class="table table-bordered table-condensed"  align="left"><tr>'+
        '<td width="20"align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="X" name="articulo[]" id="articulo"/></td> '+
        '<td width="74"> <input name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" type="text"  maxlength="5" size="5" value="" > </td>'+
        '<td width="50"align="center"><div class="txtHint"> *</div></td>'+
        '<td width="100" align="left"><input onmouseout ="showUser(this.value)" type="text" size="50"   class="service" name="service[]" /></td><div class="suggestions"></div> ' +
        '</tr></table>'
    );
```

**this one is the loop i tried to use**

```
 function showUser(str){

if (str == "") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint")[0].innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           var divs=getElementsByClassName("txtHint");
           for(var x=0;x<divs.length;x++){
            divs[x].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }}
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","busca.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}}
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can't assign `innerHTML` of `getElementsByClassName`'s result as it returns an array-like object.

Comment: using a for loop should work, you probably did it incorrectly. Including that in your question would have been useful.

Comment: ok i will edit the post and put my loop

Comment: yeah, that for loop should have worked. Are you sure said divs actually exist?

Comment: well it does not. i just work on the first input but it does not return the stock of the product its weird

Comment: ive already edit the post because i think its confuse what im tryibng to achive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok now with this new scrip when i moveout of the any textbox it change the value of All of the Exist Act column.Is there a solution so the script just change the value on the same row?

You are doing everything right. The only problem is you are using this code

```
$('.txtHint').html(data);
```

in your ajax success method, What this does is it will select all the elements with the class `txtHint` in the entire table and then change all of them. You need to select only this respective row element with the class `txtHint` So what you can do is traverse to top to find the `tr` in which this input element is wrapped and then find the `txtHint` class named element within this `tr` and change only that. So use the below code

```
$this.closest('tr').find('.txtHint').html(data);
```

Since you already have `$this` this will hold the current input element which triggered the event and then `$this.closest('tr')` will get you the parent tr in which the input is wrapped, Now trace down to the element with class `txtHint` inside this tr and then change only that.

Comment: NIce! thanks a lot , im  understanding jquery thanks to this comunity  :)

Comment: @LuisF.Huerta Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery and all of your elements containers will have the `.input` class then use `$(".input").html()` to access the html of the element. Now if you need to use an event on the dynamically created element then that is a different story. First you will have to select the document or an element that already existed when the page first loaded in order for events to fire on the dynamically created element. See example Below:

**Example HTML created dynamically:**

```
 <!--pretend this was added using the JQuery append() function-->
  <div class="input">I was added dynamically</div>
```

**JQuery Event:**

```
 //select the document for example first then the selector
 $(document).on("mouseover",".input",function(){//begin event

          //do something when the event is fired

          //alert the html of element hovered over with an input class
          alert($(this).html());


 });//end event
```

**Update:**

The following code will change only td element in a single row after the mouse leaves the .service class element. Replace `$('.txtHint').html(data);` in your ajax success function with the following code:

```
/* Select the parent element which is a 
  td element and then select the previous
  td element which contains the txtHint class 
  */
  $(this).parent().prev("td").html(data);
```

Comment: ok i have change the script but now it changes the whole column insted of just on the same row

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would look over how selectors work in jQuery. Unless necessary, I would by consistent with using only one form of selecting elements (i.e. either, jQuery or document.getElementBy...).

The basic selectors from jQuery are:

`$("tagName")` about equivalent to `document.GetElementsByTagName`

`$(".className")`about equivalent to `document.GetElementsByClassName`

`$("#id")`about equivalent to `document.GetElementById`

You should notice that the first two return multiple items and only the last returns a single element (the first found with that id).

`document.getElementsByClassName("txtHint").innerHTML = "";`

Is not valid since you get a NodeList and trying to set the innerHTML. jQuery lets you get away with this since it will run/set most things for the whole list of returned items.

`$('.inputs').append(..)`

Tries to find all the elements with `class="inputs"` and append HTML to them. In your case you probably want a specific id for the input, so `$("#service").append()`

Depending on the project it may be cleaner to pass the element to whichever function needs to append to the element.

`onmouseout="showUser(this)"`
and then use `this` in the function

```
function showUser(element) {
var str = element.value;
....
$(element).append(...);
}}
```

But that depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve and the methods purpose.

All the jQuery Selectors are on their website:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ Search of what you need.

Comment: woow nice answer i need to read a lot of jquery. i will try to re-write the script, well what im trying to do do is when the user fills the input it will display the stock of that pruduct on a diferent column i already edit the post, to explain that

Comment: ive change the whole script but i got a problem